# How to find the brier score of a logistic regression model in R?

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I have created a Logistic regression model and used it to predict attendance:

```
LogModel <- glm(formula = Attended ~ City + Duration, 
                family = binomial(logit), data = MyData)
prediction <- predict(LogModel, MyData, type = "response")
```

What should be the arguments I use in the `brierscore()` function in order to obtain the brier score?

Comment: Not sure where you are getting `brierscore`-function. The print method for `rms::lrm` which does the same modeling as glm(..., family ="binomial") prints a Brier score. Looking at the code it appears there is a `stats` item in the model returned by `lrm`.

Answer (score 5):

Note that for a glm fit, `fit$residuals` will return the **working** residuals, as opposed to the predicted probabilities. Predicted probabilities can be obtained using `residuals(fit,type='response')`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531489/understanding-glmresiduals-and-residglm) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1432/what-do-the-residuals-in-a-logistic-regression-mean) for posts on residual types from a glm fit.

Here is an example of computing the Brier Score using the `mtcars` dataset:

```
fit <- glm(am~hp+wt,data=mtcars,family='binomial')
pred.prob <- predict(fit,type='response')
brierScore <- mean((pred.prob-mtcars$am)^2)
# 0.04659236
```

Here is [another post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67114/brier-versus-aic) on how to calculate the Brier Score.

Answer (score 2):

The Brier score is effectively the mean of the squared residuals. The residuals are stored in every `glm` model output. So you can just do it by hand:

```
# Create some data (from ?profile.glm)
ldose <- rep(0:5, 2)
numdead <- c(1, 4, 9, 13, 18, 20, 0, 2, 6, 10, 12, 16)
sex <- factor(rep(c("M", "F"), c(6, 6)))
SF <- cbind(numdead, numalive = 20 - numdead)
# Run a model
budworm.lg0 <- glm(SF ~ sex + ldose - 1, family = binomial)
# Brier score
mean(budworm.lg0$residuals^2)
```

Comment: As noted on the [Wikipedia entry for Brier score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brier_score), this isn't the exact formulation used by Brier, but it is the most commonly used.